# How to prevent 'Request for principal permission failed' from faulting WCF client?

Tags: wcf, authorization, principal

I have a WCF service with several operation.
Each operation has the 'PrincipalPermission' tag, something like this :

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrator")]
public ProductsDto GetAllProducts()
{
     // Do operation here ...
}
```

Problem is - if the user is not part of the role 'Administratir' - the service throws the exception

**Request for principal permission failed**

This corrupts the client's channel to a 'Faulted' state.

I want to be able to catch this somehow and send the client a 'Fault' message,

so that the client knows he tried to do something he shouldn't, without faulting the channel !

I tried using a 'try-catch' block inside the operation, but it didn't help.
The exception occurs 'outside' the operation itself.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a special interface [`IErrorHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) that you can implement and hook up with the WCF service to handle the exception. Using `IErrorHandler` will let you handle both the security exceptions and any exceptions thrown by the serialization code.

Another note on the client's channel getting into a faulted state: I'd recomment creating a new client object for each unit of work you perform from the client. Reusing the client object opens up for this kinds of problems.

Comment: I don't want to open a client for each request, because there is also a polling mechanism that happens every 60 seconds, and also - the client needs to feed username & password, and I don't want to store them in the client's memory.

Can you please elaborate a bit more on how IErrorHandler solves my problem ? How can I catch the PRINCIPAL error and send an appropriate message to the client without faulting it ?